# How to display last query in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use :

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());
```

But it's not working.

My service is like this :

```
public function dataCustomerList($param) 
    {
        $status = $param['status_sort'];
        $gender = $param['gender'];
        $published = $param['published'];

        if($published=='NO'){
            $published_check = 'NO';
            $published = 0;
        }
        else if($published=='YES'){
            $published_check = 'YES';
            $published = 1;
        }
 DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
        $customer = customer::paginate(10);

        if(!empty($status)) {
            // die($status);
            $customer = customer::where('tb_customer.customer_status', '=', $status)->paginate(10);
        }

        if (!empty($gender)) {
            $customer = customer::where('tb_customer.gender', '=', $gender)->paginate(10);
        }

        if (!empty($published_check)) {
            $customer = customer::where('tb_customer.published', '=', $published)->paginate(10);
        }
        var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());
        return $customer;


    }
```

When I run it, query does not appear

The result is like this :

```
array(0) {
}
```

How to get the query executed in Laravel 5?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried Laravel Debugbar? It can show you all queries performed in a request (with time and improvement suggestions): https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen to [query events on DB](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries):

```
DB::listen(function($query) {
    var_dump($query->sql);
});
```

Comment: Do not forget to put this code without the `$bindings` and `$time` to `AppServiceProvider`, `boot` method